# How can I group adjacent not-empty cells?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a 4x4 cell array `C`, which

```
C= {

[1] [3] [6] [ ]; 

[2] [ ] [ ] [8];  

[ ] [4] [ ] [9]; 

[ ] [5] [7] [ ]}
```

I want to generate a new cell array D which give me

```
D = {[1;2], [3], [4;5],[6],[7],[8;9]}
```

basically I want to 1. combine the adjacent non empty cell in each column vertically and 2. output the new cell array `D` contains the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. I've used bwlabel from the imaging toolkit:

```
C= {                   ...
[1] [3] [6] [ ];       ...
[2] [ ] [ ] [8];       ...
[ ] [4] [ ] [9];       ...
[ ] [5] [7] [ ]};

lenf = @(X)~isempty(X);
lens = cellfun(lenf, C);
```

`lens` is now a logical array indicating if any slot in C is empty or not. Now we can construct `D` by treating each column in `lens` as a 1 x *whatever* binary image, and seek regions using `bwlabel()`. Finally we put the regions into D.

```
sum = 0;
for k = 1:size(lens,2)
    [L,num] = bwlabel(lens(:,k), 4);
    for idx = 1:num
        D{idx+sum} = cat(1, C{L==idx, k});
    end
    sum = sum + num;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Without depending on another toolbox, you could use this code

```
nextGroup = diff([true(1, size(C, 2)); cellfun(@isempty, C)]) < 0;
index = reshape(cumsum(nextGroup(:)), size(nextGroup));
result = arrayfun(@(x) horzcat(C{index==x}), 1:index(end,end), ...
                  'UniformOutput', false);
```

It works in Octave, so I hope, it works in Matlab, too.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the empty cells with NaN values and make it a matrix with `cell2mat` and get a logical matrix with all numbers. In a for loop you could easily get all connected values with `bwconncomp` (this will require the image toolbox).

To avoid the for loop, we can turn into a long vector with a nan separating the end of each column (by adding a row of nans before turning it into a vector).

```
C(cellfun (@isempty, C)) = {nan};
C                = cell2mat (C);
C(end+1, :)      = nan;
mask             = false (size (C));
mask(~isnan (C)) = true;
list             = regionprops (bwconncomp (mask(:)), C(:), 'PixelValues')
```

`list` is a struct array so you get a cs-list when you try to access it. You can place all the values into a cell array with:

```
D = {list(:).Pixelvalues}
```